# Saving Scope Data in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am working on a project where I have to save data of scope. I am using the code shown below but its not working for me as I want to save the data after every iteration. How can I do that?

```
for i =1:numel(All_IR)
        IR=All_IR(i)
        simOut=sim('ModelName')
        Loggings(i).scopeData=scopeData
end
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "not working properly". See how to make a [mre]

Comment: Hi @cigien I mean to say its not working for me as I want to save the data after every iteration.

Comment: Please add all relevant information as an [edit] to the question, instead of adding comments with that information.

Comment: Done! Please guide if you have any idea about the problem @cigien

Comment: Can you use a `ToWorkspace` block instead, then you will have the data available in the workspace and can just `save` it? Scopes are more applicable for viewing data than extracting it, that's why `ToWorkspace` exists. If the code you provided already gets the desired data, why isn't doing a `save` within your loop already working?

Comment: Hi @Wolfie, The `save` option only saves the data of last iteration. Same is the case with `To Workspace`. In my case, I need data of Scope after every iteration. Can you help in this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're defining as an "iteration" - the simulation runs to completion, outputting data at every time sample to both scopes and `ToWorkspace` blocks, and you can `save` that timeseries data after each `sim` command

Comment: @Wolfie I mean to say iteration as in `for loop`. I want to save data after each iteration say if `i=5` I want to save data 5 times (5 iterations).
It would be great if you share a piece of code of what you are saying in your last comment.

Comment: In the loop you've shown, when `i=5` you do a single simulation (having already done a single simulation when `i=1`, when `i=2` etc). You want to save once for each `i`? In which case just add something like `save( ['desired\output\folder\' num2str(i) '.mat'], 'simData' )` where `simData` is the variable containing data would work? Not clear what else you need

Comment: See (this link)[https://www.mathworks.com/help/sldrt/ug/set-scope-parameters-for-logging-to-workspace.html] It explains how you can set up your Scope block to log its output to workspace and define the variable name, which judging from your code you need to set as "scopeData"